# jQuery: Keeping two divs at constant distance during an animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, show

I am adding a div to a page using jQuery `.show()`.  During this animation, I want another div to stay at a constant distance from the first, so that they both move together smoothly.

Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/xrJ4T/11/

Instead of moving in a smooth synchronized way, the bottom div jumps to its end position immediately.

I tried using the `{step: function(now, fx) {}}` option with jQuery `.show()`, but it would not run the step function.  For example:

```
$("#login_pod").show({
    effect: "drop",
    direction: 'up',
    queue: false,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 1000
    step: function(now, fx) {
        $("#second_pod").animate(marginTop: "+=2px");
    }
});
```

What is the best way to keep a constant distance between two animating divs?  Why won't the step function work?

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `#` from `second_pod Id` try this,

```
$("#second_pod").animate(marginTop: "+=2px");// in step function
//-^---- you missed #
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.  This does not solve the animation problem though.